# How validate file upload max size 500KB

Tags: yii2

How validating the upload files size by up to 500Kb?
I'm doing well, but it's not working out:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
...
           'myfile'
            ], 'file', 'extensions' => 'pdf, jpg', 'maxSize' => 4096000, 'tooBig' => 'Limit is 500KB' ],
        ];
    }
```

Comment: `maxSize` should be 512000 (500 * 1024). What do you mean by "not working"? Also add code related with handling of uploaded file, seems like the problem is there.

Comment: Glad to help, I wrote this as answer with more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You specified wrong `maxSize`.

From offical docs:

> The maximum number of bytes required for the uploaded file. Defaults
>   to null, meaning no limit. Note, the size limit is also affected by
>   'upload_max_filesize' INI setting and the 'MAX_FILE_SIZE' hidden field
>   value.
>
> See also $tooBig for the customized message for a file that is too
>   big.

500 kilobytes is 500 * 1024 bytes = 512 000 bytes.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['myfile', 'file', 'extensions' => 'pdf, jpg', 'maxSize' => 512000, 'tooBig' => 'Limit is 500KB'],
    ];
}
```

Also you can specify it like `'maxSize' => 500 * 1024`, this is more readable and you don't have to do any calculations (for more complex measure units this is preferable option).

**Useful links:**

- [What is kilobyte?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilobyte)
- [FileValidator $maxSize](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-filevalidator.html#$maxSize-detail)